# How to encapsulate this code as a function in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(_T("Test1.dll"));
if (NULL ！= hDll)
{
    typedef CTest1Dlg*(*pDllFun)(int val);
    pDllFun pDlg = (pDllFun)GetProcAddress(hDll, "ShowDlg");
    if (NULL ！= pDlg)
    {
        pDlg(val);
    }
}
```

Mainly: `typedef CTest1Dlg*(*pDllFun)(int val);`

The only difference in this line of code is that `CTest1Dlg` is different, it will become `CTest2Dlg` or other, but their parameters are the same

Comment: In C++, when types appear as something which should become parameter, you need a [template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates). If you are not common with templates, be prepared: That's a language on its own (in the language C++). ;-)

Comment: Using *templates*?

Comment: The template doesn't seem to fit my idea

Comment: @wsy why not? The function template gives you what you want, you have boilerplate code with a 'placeholder' that you can fill in on each instantiation. `CTest1Dlg` is the type you would fill in each time, in that case.

Comment: @BasGroothedde Would you please help me write it out and let me study it

Comment: The solution by @molbdnilo should suffice in explaining what the templates can be used for in your case.

Answer (score 3):

This suits a function template.

The most straightforward parametrization would probably be

```
template<typename Dlg>
void testDllFunction(LPCTSTR dll, const char* name, int val)
{
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(dll);
    if (hDll != NULL)
    {
        typedef Dlg*(*pDllFun)(int);
        pDllFun pDlg = reinterpret_cast<pDllFun>(GetProcAddress(hDll, name));
        if (pDlg ！= NULL)
        {
            pDlg(val);
        }
    }
}


// ...

testDllFunction<CTest1Dlg>(_T("Test1.dll"), "ShowDlg"));
```

But it's probably a good idea to separate the loading of the function from the calling of it.
Here's one suggestion for that:

```
template<typename Dlg>
using DlgFunction = Dlg*(*)();

template<typename Dlg>
bool loadFunction(LPCTSTR dll, const char* name, DlgFunction<Dlg>& fun)
{
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(dll);
    if (!hDll)
        return false;
    fun = reinterpret_cast<DlgFunction<Dlg>>(GetProcAddress(hDll, name));
    return fun != NULL
}

// ...

DlgFunction<CTest1Dlg> test1;
if (loadFunction(_T("Test1.dll"), "ShowDlg", test1))
    test1(12);
DlgFunction<CTest2Dlg> test2;
if (loadFunction(_T("Test2.dll"), "Kittens", test2))
    test2(34);
```

Comment: Without specifying the [calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/calling-conventions) the code works by coincidence only. And break in spectacular ways if it doesn't.